# NodeJS - syncronize two listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, asynchronous

I have a Node.JS server that listens on two ports. The standard HTTP is on port 3000 and it provides an API with two routes: `/getInfo` and `/sendCommand`. I have another listener on 3001 for a specific protocol, where a device is connected. The goal is to execute an API call from the web interface and send it to the device in order to receive the output. Something like:

```
GET localhost:3000/getInfo
server sends command to the device connected on localhost:3001
server receives some output
server responses to the request
```

How should the code look like since Node.JS requests and responses are asynchronous with the other server?

Server for devices:

```
var raspberryList = [];

function sendCommand(name, command) {
    for (var i = 0; i < raspberryList.length; i++) {
        if (!raspberryList[i].name.localeCompare(name)) {
            raspberryList[i].write(command);
        }
    }
}

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.name = socket.remoteAddress;
    console.log(socket.name + " joined.";
    raspberryList.push(socket);

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        // TODO: Data received here should be displayed into the web interface
        console.log(socket.name + " > " + data);
    });

    socket.on('end', function() {
        raspberryList.splice(raspberryList.indexOf(socket), 1);
        console.log(socket.name + " left.");
    });

});
```

Node.JS API route:

```
app.post('/getInfo', function(req, res) {
    // TODO: send the command somehow and get the output

    // Send the response
    res.send(response);
});
```

Comment: `rasperyList` should be a `Set`. And you need some way of identification between the devices. E.g. one receives a random id, the other one can connect to that

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but there is a bigger problem :D

Comment: Theres also a question which is necessary to get meaningful answers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTTP on port 3001 you can try using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

```
var request = require('request');
app.post('/getInfo', function(req, res) {

request('http://localhost:3000/endpoint', function (error, response, body) {

if (error) throw error;

res.send(body);
 });
 });
```